# Wishlist organized into categories in Wix Velo?

Tags: velo

is there a way to make items in a member's wishlist page be shown categorized by their store category with Velo?
So instead of all of them being in a one big chaotic list, categories based on the products' store categories would be made and wishlisted items would be where they belong?

I'm trying to get better at Velo on my own, but it's a struggle..